# I'm using iTerm to run the command line on my mac. Its in a mode I don't recognize

Tags: osx, iterm

I like to use iterm on my mac. Recently when I open iTerm or a new tab, it's in a mode I don't recognize. whenever I start typing a command, iTerm lists all previous versions of that command.  see image below.

[image]

Why is in this mode. if I type bash on the command line it leaves this mode. Why does it open in this mode and how do I stop it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's iTerm2's [Autocomplete feature](https://iterm2.com/documentation-shell-integration.html), which is activated by pressing <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>;</kbd>.

To avoid link rot, the feature is described as follows.

> Autocomplete
>
> Commands in command history are also added to Autocomplete (Cmd-;). If Preferences>General>Save copy/paste history and command history to disk is enabled, then command history will be preserved across runs of iTerm2 (up to 200 commands per user/hostname).

Additionally...

> Command Completion
>
> iTerm2 will present command completion suggestions automatically when View>Auto Command Completion is selected.

Comment: Thank you!  You solution was perfect!